# How to put a 2D array value into another 2D array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7

I don´t know why it is not working, im just assigning values taken from the for ap loop to another bidimensional array; I get the error Syntax error: invalid syntax. Thanks for the help!

```
import errno
import sys
import types
import pythonwifi.flags
from pythonwifi.iwlibs import Wireless, WirelessInfo, Iwrange, getNICnames, getWNICnames
ArregloMAC=[]
ArregloMAC.append([])
AP1='88:DC:96:03:64:5C'
AP2='F4:B8:A7:D1:73:04'
AP3='88:DC:96:03:64:8E'
w, h = 3, 100;
MatrizFinal = [[0 for x in range(w)] for y in range(h)] 
wifi= Wireless('wlan0')
results = wifi.scan()
print "%-8.16s  Scan completed :" % (wifi.ifname,)
while i<99:
    for ap in results:
        ind = 1
        ArregloMAC[ind-1].append(ap.bssid)
        ArregloMAC[ind-1].append(ap.quality.getSignallevel())
        if(ArregloMAC[ind-1][0]==AP1){
        MatrizFinal[0][i]=ArregloMAC[ind-1][1]
        }
        if(ArregloMAC[ind-1][0]==AP2){
        MatrizFinal[1][i]=ArregloMAC[ind-1][1]
        }
        if(ArregloMAC[ind-1][0]==AP3){
        MatrizFinal[2][i]=ArregloMAC[ind-1][1]
        }
        ind = ind+1
        i=i+1
print MatrizFinal
```

Comment: Where do you get the syntax error? I'm guessing it's the first place you tried to use curly braces in your `if` statements. :-) Python doesn't use curly braces like that.

Comment: Ohhh! i forgot that hahaha i will fix it right now

Comment: Okay, there are no more syntax problems, now it says the index is out of range... any suggestions?

Comment: Edit your post, put in your current code, put in the full error message (including what line it happens on).